# Enum as parameter in step definition in Cucumber (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, testing, cucumber, playwright, cucumberjs

Can you tell me is there any way to use enum as parameter in step definition ? :/
e.g.

```
User opened page on selected {MyEnum} tab'
```

I found the example how I could create a new parameter on https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-expressions#readme

but I'm not good in TS :/

Below I pasted an example of creating new parameter  from upper link :)

```
import { defineParameterType } from '@cucumber/cucumber'

defineParameterType({
    name: 'color',
    regexp: /red|blue|yellow/,
    transformer: s => new Color(s)
})
```

I want to do it using Typescript :)
Thanks for any tips :)

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This question is not well formed.